# FFmpeg: Detect silences above digital silence?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'd like to use the silencedetect filter from FFmpeg to detect silences in audio files but I want to ignore digital silence/absolute silence. I would think this should be as simple as specifying a range for the n= option (something like `silencedetect=n=[0:0.0001]:d=1`). Is it possible to specify a range, and if so, what's the syntax?